# Compare character to the elements inside a array of strings in Java

Tags: java

```
public static int getDigit(char character, char letters[]  )
{
    int digit=0;
    for (int i=0;i<=0;i++);
    {
        for (int j=0; j<(letters[i].length());j++)
        {
            if (letters[i][j]==character)
            {
               digit=i; 
            }
        }    
    }
    return digit;
}
```

> where array is LETTERS={("abc"),("def"),("ghi"),("jkl"),
>           ("mno)"),("pqrs"),("tuv"),("wxyz")}; and character could be any alphabet.

I want program to find a character entered and to display the location of that in the string. Eg- If user enters letter "g" then it should display number 3 because it is in 3rd element of array.

Comment: You should make sure the type of `letters` is correct.

Comment: How can I fix that?

Comment: Did you ask a question?  Does your code fail to do what you intended?  If so, what did it do?

Comment: I doesn't work. Thats why I posted it here.

Comment: Can you post the portion of the code where `getDigit` is called?

Comment: `letters` is a 1D array in your code, yet your problem statement appears to expect it to be a 2D array or a list.  Start with that.

Comment: You didn't post enough information about what currently happens and what you expect to happen.

Comment: In your parameters you are accepting char array while your sample input seems to be a string array. Please be specific of what is required

Comment: https://pastebin.com/JUfajRnT is the code I made for the problem that was asked in our class test yesterday and I failed in my class test. Thats why I am wondering about the solution... The problem is--- http://www-acad.sheridanc.on.ca/~jollymor/prog10082/lab5_Fall16.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working implementation of what you appear to want.  I assume that your `letters` array is intended to be a 2D jagged character array.  Your original code really only had a few minor issues, mainly in the loop logic.

```
public static int getDigit(char character, char letters[][]) {
    int digit = -1; // return -1 if character not found

    for (int i=0;i < letters.length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < letters[i].length; j++) {
            if (letters[i][j] == character) {
                digit = i;
                i = letters.length;
                break;
            }
        }    
    }

    return digit;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    char[][] letters = new char[][] {
        { 'a', 'b', 'c' },
        { 'd', 'e', 'f' },
        { 'g', 'h', 'i' },
        { 'j', 'k', 'l' },
        { 'm', 'n', 'o' },
        { 'p', 'q', 'r', 's' },
        { 't', 'u', 'v' },
        { 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' }};
    System.out.println(getDigit('d', letters) );
}
```

### Demo

Comment: Yes your solution to problem is working Could you please give me exact solution (if possible) because I am beginner in Java. __________________________________________________________||   pastebin.com/JUfajRnT   | is the code I made for the problem that was asked in our class test yesterday and I failed in my class test. Thats why I am wondering about the solution... The problem is---     |  www-acad.sheridanc.on.ca/~jollymor/prog10082/lab5_Fall16.htm‌​l  |

Comment: I have answered your question.  I'm not opening your course website, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

It's not really possible to completely answer you question because it doesn't say what the problem is besides "it doesn't work".

Just skimming the code: you should probably change the line `digit=i;` to `return i + 1;` because you said it should return 3 if "g" is the third character.

Also, this loop is nonsense `for (int i=0;i<=0;i++);` It will run only once ever... Also as @bcsb1001 pointed out in the comments, the semicolon at the end of the loop essentially ends it, so the loop is actually empty! It should be `for (int i=0;i<letters.length();i++) {`

There might be other issues with this code. You didn't share enough.

Comment: As well as only running once, the body of that `for` loop is empty due to the erroneous semicolon.

Comment: Wow, negative score because I didn't completely do his homework for him. Cool.